# Geometry of shape

Tags: geometry

[image]

Find x in terms of r, 
I could not figure out anyway that i would apply Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Join $O_1$ to $S$. Extend $SR$ to meet $O_1A$.